# Using Git, what is the best way to allow people to see different versions of the same project?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm a UX designer and we use Git to version control the prototypes we create for our main project.

However, my aim is to have a 'Dashboard' homepage, where users can click on links and directly open up the different versions (feature branches?) of our main project.

This will allow us to demonstrate the journey we have taken and the decisions we have made along the way - but I'm not quite sure how to achieve all of this using Git.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would probably do it manually (check out each branch, upload, add link to page) :P

Comment: Surely there must be a better way than doing it manually? I thought that this would be a common issue? I'd want to avoid doing something like www.prototype.com/v1, www.prototype.com/v2 etc...

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. What exactly do you want on the “dashboard”? Where is your repo?

Comment: You could iterate over the list of branches.

Comment: You appear to want to build a service on *top* of Git, rather than doing anything *in* Git.

Comment: I think perhaps you're right... We use heroku to deploy our app, so maybe we need to deploy a version of our app to that - and then link to that version from our dashboard page.

Answer (score 0):

Export to github/gitlab.com, and explore the repo with a webbrowser. If exporting is not an option, run a private gitlab instance and explore the repo with a webbrowser.

If each content of a branch or tag must be built and/or exported (like a binary), an dedicated exporter for a given revision is required. How exactly that looks like depends highly on what exactly is in that git repo. There are these CI modules, which most likely also exists for gitlab. They can probably build and export a given branch, based on rules that have to be created by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things going on here.

First, there's the question of how to use git to represent the things you want to show.  If you're talking about A/B testing multiple candidate designs, then you might want to use branches

x -- x -- x -- A <--(versionA)
         \
          x -- B <--(versionB)

So each branch is a different direction the design might have taken.

But when you mention something about showing the journey, that suggests you might want to keep track of specific historical versions, not to compare them with one another but rather to show how you got to the proposed design.  In that case, you could use tags.

```
x -- x -- x -- x -- A <--(versionA)
     ^v0.1     ^v0.2
```

Of course these could be combined, with tags showing key historical versions of each of a set of candidate designs.

```
x -- x -- x -- x -- A <--(versionA)
 \   ^vA=0.1   ^A-v0.2
  \
   x -- x -- x -- B <--(versionB)
        ^vB-0.1
```

The other issue is that to "show" each prototype version, you have to check it out.  If there aren't too many versions, it may be simplest to just check them each out to a different work tree as part of your demo setup, and then link each version statically from the dashboard.

If there are many versions, or versions frequently change, or for whatever reason maintenance would get to be too much with a manual approach, then you could instead code the dashboard to check out a selected version (by tag or branch) to a temporary work area from which it can be displayed.  You would have to be able to properly coordinate both git, and the client interface that displays the prototypes.  (For example, if the prototypes are viewed over the web, then you would have to check them out to a location and make sure your web server can map a URL to that location.  If concurrent access by multiple users is a concern - as it probably would be over the web - then you'd want to make sure multiple versions could be checked out at once, such as by dynamically creating a temporary path for each, or by having a "formula" for mapping tag/branch names to checkout paths.)

For the dashboard to access git, you could either use system calls to invoke the git command-line tool, or use a git library for whatever language the dashboard is written in (e.g. something like JGit if the dashboard is written in java).